# Why is terraform saying that my object has no attributes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using terraform 0.12.31 and trying to create some AWS SES resources. There's one which is returning an error message:

```
    aws_ses_domain_identity.ses_domain_per_tenant is object with no attributes
    each.key is "a.env.account.info"

    aws_ses_domain_identity.ses_domain_per_tenant is object with no attributes
    each.key is "b.env.account.info"
    
    aws_ses_domain_identity.ses_domain_per_tenant is object with no attributes
    each.key is "c.env.account.info"
```

This is my code:

```
resource "aws_ses_domain_identity" "ses_domain_per_tenant" {
  for_each  = toset(var.enable_per_tenant_email_domain ? var.tenants_email_domain : [])
  domain    = each.key
}

resource "aws_ses_domain_dkim" "dkim_domain_per_tenant" {
  for_each  = toset(var.enable_per_tenant_email_domain ? var.tenants_email_domain : [])
  domain    = aws_ses_domain_identity.ses_domain_per_tenant[each.key].domain
}
```

I also have this resource as part of the same code, which is working fine:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "ses_amazonses_verification_record_per_tenant" {
  for_each  = toset(var.enable_per_tenant_email_domain ? var.tenants_email_domain : [])
  records   = [aws_ses_domain_identity.ses_domain_per_tenant[each.key].verification_token]
}
```

Where:

```
tenants_email_domain = ['a.env.account.info', 'b.env.account.info', 'c.env.account.info']
```

What's happening here?

Comment: Well, what is the value of the `var.enable_per_tenant_email_domain` variable?

Comment: That variable is set to “true”. I’m sure that the domain identity will be created, but could it be that because I’m using for_each, then terraform will only know the resource id after it gets created and thus this error?

Comment: The only issue I see is the single quotes around variable values, i.e., `'a.env.account.info'` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for having the way you are currently using `for_each` meta-argument, there is an additional thing you can do which can also help avoiding some of the errors and duplicating code and that is chaining `for_each` between resources [1]:

```
resource "aws_ses_domain_identity" "ses_domain_per_tenant" {
  for_each = toset(var.enable_per_tenant_email_domain ? var.tenants_email_domain : [])
  domain   = each.key
}

resource "aws_ses_domain_dkim" "dkim_domain_per_tenant" {
  for_each = aws_ses_domain_identity.ses_domain_per_tenant
  domain   = each.value.domain
}
```

Of course, in order for this to work, the values assigned to the `tenants_email_domain` have to be fixed to be strings:

```
tenants_email_domain = ["a.env.account.info", "b.env.account.info", "c.env.account.info"]
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments the issue is because of the variable `tenants_email_domain` value having single quotes `'`.

On the [terraform string documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings) also they only mention string literals only with `"`.

The following code generates a valid plan.

```
resource "aws_ses_domain_identity" "ses_domain_per_tenant" {
  for_each = toset(var.enable_per_tenant_email_domain ? var.tenants_email_domain : [])
  domain   = each.key
}

resource "aws_ses_domain_dkim" "dkim_domain_per_tenant" {
  for_each = toset(var.enable_per_tenant_email_domain ? var.tenants_email_domain : [])
  domain   = aws_ses_domain_identity.ses_domain_per_tenant[each.key].domain
}

variable "tenants_email_domain" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["a.env.account.info", "b.env.account.info", "c.env.account.info"] ## updated ` with "" ##
}
variable "enable_per_tenant_email_domain" {
  type = bool
  default = true
}
```